# Open android Gallery App from react native app

Tags: android, react-native, android-gallery

My application requires opening an image, stored locally in the document directories using the android gallery app.Is this possible in react native using linking.

Comment: try this library: react-native-image-picker

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So my requirement was to download an image on a button click an then open the same image using the android gallery , I achieved the same using [react-native-fetch-blob](https://github.com/wkh237/react-native-fetch-blob) which facilitates both downloading a file and opening it with the corresponding apps. P.S: you could also open the gallery using [linking](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/linking.html), provided you have the content url rather than file url.

Answer (score 0):

Use this permission in AndroidManifest.XML

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_MEDIA_IMAGES"/>
```

which can allow users to access the gallery to pick an image or video whenever we use the imagepicker.

We successfully used and solved this issue in our app ! so, Its working

```js
This XML file does not appear to have any style information associated with it. The document tree is shown below.
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" package="com.nano.smartfm.reachv5">
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_MEDIA_IMAGES"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.DOWNLOAD_WITHOUT_NOTIFICATION"/>
<queries>
<!--  Camera  -->
<intent>
<action android:name="android.media.action.IMAGE_CAPTURE"/>
</intent>
<!--  Gallery  -->
<intent>
<action android:name="android.intent.action.GET_CONTENT"/>
<data android:mimeType="image/*"/>
</intent>
<intent>
<action android:name="android.intent.action.PICK"/>
<data android:mimeType="image/*"/>
</intent>
<intent>
<action android:name="android.intent.action.CHOOSER"/>
</intent>
<intent>
<action android:name="android.speech.RecognitionService"/>
</intent>
</queries>
<application android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true" android:name=".MainApplication" android:label="@string/app_name" android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher" android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round" android:allowBackup="false" android:theme="@style/AppTheme" android:usesCleartextTraffic="true" android:largeHeap="true">
<activity android:name=".MainActivity" android:label="@string/app_name" android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize|uiMode" android:launchMode="singleTask" android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize" android:exported="true">
<intent-filter>
<action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
<category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
<action android:name="android.intent.action.DOWNLOAD_COMPLETE"/>
</intent-filter>
</activity>
<activity android:name="com.facebook.react.devsupport.DevSettingsActivity"/>
<meta-data android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY" android:value="AIzaSyDoEK24faySzWqhom_1zsEzOXQiA5bx8pw"/>
<meta-data android:name="com.dieam.reactnativepushnotification.channel_create_default" android:value="false"/>
<meta-data android:name="com.dieam.reactnativepushnotification.notification_foreground" android:value="true"/>
<meta-data android:name="com.dieam.reactnativepushnotification.notification_color" android:resource="@android:color/white"/>
<receiver android:name="com.dieam.reactnativepushnotification.modules.RNPushNotificationActions"/>
<receiver android:name="com.dieam.reactnativepushnotification.modules.RNPushNotificationPublisher"/>
<receiver android:name="com.dieam.reactnativepushnotification.modules.RNPushNotificationBootEventReceiver" android:exported="false">
<intent-filter>
<action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
<action android:name="android.intent.action.QUICKBOOT_POWERON"/>
<action android:name="com.htc.intent.action.QUICKBOOT_POWERON"/>
</intent-filter>
</receiver>
<service android:name="com.dieam.reactnativepushnotification.modules.RNPushNotificationListenerService" android:exported="false">
<intent-filter>
<action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT"/>
</intent-filter>
</service>
<service android:name="io.invertase.firebase.messaging.RNFirebaseMessagingService" android:exported="false">
<intent-filter>
<action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT"/>
</intent-filter>
</service>
<service android:name="io.invertase.firebase.messaging.RNFirebaseInstanceIdService" android:exported="false">
<intent-filter>
<action android:name="com.google.firebase.INSTANCE_ID_EVENT"/>
</intent-filter>
</service>
</application>
</manifest>
```