# Viewing an Image Saved in Cache in React Native

Tags: react-native

I am currently trying to open an image that's saved in the cache from the `react-native-camera` module. According to this [Open android Gallery App from react native app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47268439/open-android-gallery-app-from-react-native-app) they managed to do it when they passed in the `content://` url instead of the `file://` url, but after some research I can't find anything on converting file uris to content - only the opposite. I can get the image file paths by:

```
import RNFS from 'react-native-fs'
import { Linking } from 'react-native'

RNFS.readDir(RNFS.CachesDirectoryPath)
.then(arr => RNFS.readDir(arr[0].path)) // The Camera directory
.then(arr => arr.forEach(item => {
    const contentURI = somehowConvertPathToContentURI(item.path)

    Linking.canOpenURL(contentURI)
    .then(able => able ? Linking.openURL(contentURI) : console.log('No application available'))
    .catch(console.log)
}))
.catch(console.log)
```

A logged path would be `/data/user/0/com.myapp/cache/Camera/ad8db2ca-4739-47cc-b18d-c5147c8c26e0.jpg`. Adding `file://` in front will give me the file uri, what about `content://`?

As a side note, I'm able to directly show the image if I read and convert it to base64 with `react-native-fs`, then providing the base64 to react-native's `<Image>` component - but I'd like to open the app with a gallery application